# Removing lists within a nested list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am have a nested list with the following:

```
[['X', 0],
['X', 0],
['X', ''],
['X', '']]

for i in myList:
    if i[1] == 0:
         myList.remove(i)
```

This will only remove the first list. Output would be:

```
[['X', 0],
['X', ''],
['X', '']]
```

How can I get it for both?

Comment: Don't change a list when you're iterating over it...

Comment: when you `remove(i)`, you change the list you're iterating over. So when you remove element 0, your loop will continue on with element 1, but what previously *was* element 1 is now element 0, because the previous element 0 was removed, so you skip a value.

Comment: As above but if you want to use the nethod you are using you will need to iterate over the list in reverse: `for i in reversed(range(len(myList))):`

Comment: Or make a copy of the original list by using `for i in myList[:]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `list comprehension` . Do not delete an element from a list while iterating over it.

**Ex:**

```
s = [['X', 0],
['X', 0],
['X', ''],
['X', '']]

print([i for i in s if i[1] != 0])
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but you were faster. This is a better approach then iterating and changing the original list.

Comment: 'Do not delete an element from a list while iterating over it.' Yea I knew it was bad practise and the source of why it was not working. Thanks for your input and help  :)